# How can I setup CoreOS cluster on across multiple data centers?

Tags: coreos, etcd

I thought it is as simple as using public ip instead of private ip so that the machines can see each other, but that is not the case.

Here is my cloud-config file, which is very basic.

```
#cloud-config

coreos:
  etcd:
    # generate a new token for each unique cluster from https://discovery.etcd.io/new
    discovery: https://discovery.etcd.io/<token>
    # use $public_ipv4 if your datacenter of choice does not support private networking
    addr: $public_ipv4:4001
    peer-addr: $public_ipv4:7001
  fleet:
    public-ip: $public_ipv4   # used for fleetctl ssh command
  units:
    - name: etcd.service
      command: start
    - name: fleet.service
      command: start
```

What do I need to have the cluster span across multiple data centres? For example, I use Digital Ocean and provision a machine in Singapore, another in New York, and another in Amsterdam.

My secondary question is, since I cannot find support for this use case easily, I wonder if this is not a recommended way to use CoreOS, and if it is not, could you tell me what is the prefer way to distribute my services across multiple data centres?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but it requires tuning your etcd cluster. The distances you are talking about are fairly large, so expect to use some long timeouts. More docs here: https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/2.0.8/tuning.html

Comment: So what you are saying is that my cloud-config setting is okay, but missing the timeout setting, correct?